# Access DCount Report

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to run a DCount function in a report for different circuit statistics. I am using this method to help limit the number of queries I am producing.

This issue I am facing is the number of circuits. I have 2 circuits 1234 and 5678. When I view the report both names come up properly. when I use the DCount function though it takes the number from the last record.

1234 should have 1 record
5678 should have 216 records

They are both reading 216 records.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

my DCount Function:

`Me.txt_CirCR = DCount("[_record_id]", "[tbl_VegMgnt_Management]", "[circuit] = '" & circuitName & "'")`

Yes the circuits are supposed to be strings they are not always numeric

Comment: Appart from using `DCount("*", "[tbl_VegMgnt_Management]", "[circuit] = '" & circuitName & "'")`, your syntax is correct, thus something else must be going on.

Comment: That would be expected for expression in VBA setting a textbox value. Put the calc in ControlSource property of textbox.

Comment: @June7
Thank you for your advise.

`DCount([tbl_VegMgnt_Management]![_record_id], [tbl_VegMgnt_Management], "[tbl_VegMgnt_Management]![_status] = 'Consent Required'")`

Thats is the count I was going to do. I have never done this before and I get an error that states "The specified table "tbl_VegMgnt_Management" could refer to more than one table listed in the from clause of your SQL statement."

Have you heard of this and if so what are your thoughts on the referencing

Comment: Table and field names must be within quote marks. Why are you showing expression different from one in question?